# Variable in concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure how to replace those constants I use to carry the name to the class_exec in this concern.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Groupable

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  ## [NOTE]
  #
  # Add the following attributes to your model:
  #
  # - group_id
  #

  included do
    BASE_CLASS = name
    REL_NAME = :"#{name.underscore}_items"

    belongs_to :group,
               class_name: 'Group',
               optional: true,
               inverse_of: REL_NAME

    Group.class_exec do
      has_many REL_NAME,
               class_name: BASE_CLASS, # rubocop:disable Rails/ReflectionClassName
               inverse_of: :group,
               dependent: :nullify
    end
  end
end
```

This code gives this me multiple times in my console:

```
groupable.rb:15: warning: already initialized constant Groupable::BASE_CLASS
groupable.rb:15: warning: previous definition of BASE_CLASS was here
groupable.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Groupable::REL_NAME
groupable.rb:16: warning: previous definition of REL_NAME was here
groupable.rb:15: warning: already initialized constant Groupable::BASE_CLASS
```

Comment: Do you use `REL_NAME` or `BASE_CLASS` outside of this block? If so, in what way? If not, they can just be local variables (`rel_name = ...`).

Comment: no, only inside included and the class_exec block

Answer (score 0):

You should declare constants on the class this concern is included in.

```
included(base) do
  base.const_set(:BASE_CLASS, name)
  base.const_set(:REL_NAME, :"#{name.underscore}_items")

  ...
end
```